# Remove Duplicates From Comma Delimited String

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, unique

How do I remove duplicates from a comma delimited string of integers using jquery/javascript?

My string is: 1,2,2,4,2,4,3,2,3,1,5,5,5,1,1,2

Comment: Duplicates of what? Please provide an example. I believe this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array

Comment: see these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838845/jquery-remove-duplicate-li

Comment: Split the string to create an array and follow the link I posted in my previous comment.

Comment: see this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array

Comment: There's also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506920/removing-duplicate-strings-using-javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one method, which doesn't demand writing the functionality from scratch or using some *other* js library check out [duck-punching-with-jquery](http://paulirish.com/2010/duck-punching-with-jquery/). (look for 'Example 2: $.unique() enhancement')

If you're willing to try some other library, the excellent [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org) includes a '[uniq](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq)' method which accomplishes just what you need.

Answer (score 3):

```
function spit(){
           var answer = ("1,2,2,4,2,4,3,2,3,1,5,5,5,1,1,2").split(',').filter(function(item, pos,self) {
              return self.indexOf(item) == pos;
           });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example.

```
var str1 = "a,b,c,a,d,e,b";
var characters = str1.split(",");
var distinctCharacters = [];
jQuery.each(characters, function(index, c) {
if (jQuery.inArray(c, distinctCharacters) > -1) {
        // do nothing
        alert("already exists " + c);
    } else {
        distinctCharacters.push(c);
    }
});
alert(distinctCharacters);​
```

Answer (score 1):

From  this post
[Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array)

```
var names = ["Mike","Matt","Nancy","Adam","Jenny","Nancy","Carl"];
var uniqueNames = [];
$.each(names, function(i, el){
 if($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

good answers, there is also `_.uniq()` from the library [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more elegant approach that returns the array to be a comma seperated string:

```
function removeDuplicates(str) {
    const strArr = str.split(",");
    const uniqueArray = [...new Set(strArr)];
    return uniqueArray.join();
}
```

**Code snippet:**

```js
function removeDuplicates(str) {
    const strArr = str.split(",");
    const uniqueArray = [...new Set(strArr)];
    return uniqueArray.join();
}

var myStr = '1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5';

console.log(removeDuplicates(myStr));
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are only integers, you could have something like that:

```
var array = "1,2,2,4,2,4,3,2,3,1,5,5,5,1,1,2".split(",");

array.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b });

var uniqueArray = [array[0]];

for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i - 1] !== array[i])
        uniqueArray.push(array[i]);
}

console.log(uniqueArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function in your javascript as follows:

```
Array.prototype.removeDuplicates = function () {
                return this.filter(function (item, index, self) {
                    return self.indexOf(item) == index;
                });
            };
```

then add `.removeDuplicates()` to the field you want the duplicates to be removed from after you split using the delimiter, such as:

```
var item = $("#inInputTextbox").val().split(",").removeDuplicates();
```

in your case, if i understand correctly, it could simply be:

```
var item = [a,b,c,d,d,d,c,b,a].split(",").removeDuplicates();
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
var numbersString = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
var numbersArray = numbers.split(',');
```

Now just insert with check in another array the content of `numbersArray`