# Remove duplicate words in array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a small problem with replace words in array. Ok, this my array:

```
var words = ['Category One Category One Clothes', 'Category One Category One Jackets'];
```

I want final result like this:

```
var result = ['Category One Clothes', 'Category One Jackets'];
```

Try with this method, but not working [Removing duplicate strings using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506920/removing-duplicate-strings-using-javascript)

Comment: can i recommend using lodash/uniq?  https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniq no reason to rewrite it. just reuse it

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon `uniq` will remove the duplicate elements from the **array**, not the string itself. So, it cannot be used.

Comment: Opsional - Your examples repeat the first two words only - do you want to remove words that repeat after that? Will the input array items always have the repeated words at the beginning, or might some already be just `'Category One Jackets'`?

Comment: Hay nnnnnn, Yes. the array auto-generated.

Comment: my bad i did not read the question properly. however with a little of split magic uniq could still be used `uniq(str.split(' ')).join(' ');`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**For the given input**, this should work.

```
words.map(w => w.replace(/([\w\s]+)\1+/, '$1'))
```

```js
var words = ['Category One Category One Clothes', 'Category One Category One Jackets'];
var result = words.map(w => w.replace(/([\w\s]+)\1+/, '$1'));
console.log(result);
```

The regex `([\w\s]+)` will match the words/spaces and `\1+` will match the same word again.

Comment: @Opsional Welcome. Please test all scenarios. This might not work for some inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this. I hope it will work for you.

```
function unique(array) {
    return $.grep(array, function (el, index) {
        return index == $.inArray(el, array);
    });
}
var words = ['Category One Category One Clothes', 'Category One Category One Jackets'];
var result = [];
for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    arr = unique(words[i].split(' '));
    result[i] = arr.join(' ');
}
```