# jQuery check if form data are equal

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Using jQuery to compare two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773069/using-jquery-to-compare-two-arrays)

I have to send the form data via ajax to server on say every 30 second. Now I want it to be checked at client end and ajax been hit only in case there is any change in form. I am using:

```
var lastData = "";
function saveFormInDB(){
    var $form = $("#fb_divBl0ck1").closest('form');
    var isSame = false;
    data = $form.serializeArray();
    if(lastData == ""){
        lastData = data;
    }else{
        if(lastData == data){
            isSame = true;
        }
        lastData = data;
    }
    if(!isSame){
        jqxhr = $.post("/SPSKMEForm/FormSaveServlet", data)
        .success(function() {
            if(jqxhr.responseText != ""){
                alert(jqxhr.responseText);
                alert($("#fixedFooter"));
                alert($("#fixedFooter").html());
                $("#fixedFooter").text(jqxhr.responseText).css("display", "");
                $("#fixedFooter").fadeOut("slow");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

but `isSame` is coming to be false always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your variable **lastData** is considered as a String whilst **data** is an Object. So your check will always fail and you will always have `isSame = false`.

EDIT:

> The **.serializeArray()** method creates a JavaScript **array of objects**,
>   ready to be encoded as a JSON string.

Comment: i dont think so... m assigning data to lastData.. so it will be an object also `var` can be used for all the stuff(i guess).

Comment: just check your code Varun, you will do the check and if it is true you will say isSame = true and no matter what the result of the check you will always assign lastData to data, but isSame will always be false.

Comment: +1: The .serializeArray() method creates a JavaScript array of objects, ready to be encoded as a JSON string. - http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: I know there is some issue but i doubt the reason `lastData` been given as `string` will be issue... though not sure

Comment: so what will be the best solution to check it?

Comment: @Varun: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773069/using-jquery-to-compare-two-arrays - consider yourself spoonfed :)

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this problem differently:

In your form input tags add an attribute containing the saved (original) value:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="" original="Brian">
```

Now in your jQuery, check if the values match:

```
if($('[name="name"]').attr('value') == $('[name="name"]').attr('original')) {
  //perform .post here
  //post success sets attr original to posted value
 }
```

Each time you submit data, make sure to update the "original" attribute.

Comment: will it increase efficiency? wont it be better to simply put a loop on global `data` variable and check its value