# javascript function for comparing arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, comparison

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using jQuery to compare two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773069/using-jquery-to-compare-two-arrays)

I need a Javascript or jQuery function to determine if an array contains **all** the values of another array.  The second array can have more values than the first.

This should return either `true` or `false`.  For example.

```
comparing  array1 = [1,2,3]  and  array2 = [1,2]      should return false

comparing  array1 = [1,2,3]  and  array2 = [1,1,2]    should return false

comparing  array1 = [1,2,3]  and  array2 = [3,2,1]    should return true

comparing  array1 = [1,2,3]  and  array2 = [1,2,1,3]  should return true
```

Performance is not a concern.  Thanks!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: Similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773069/using-jquery-to-compare-two-arrays. Those answers helped me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checks each element in the first array and sees if it exists in the second array.

NB. This is pure javascript, might be an easier way in jQuery.

```
var notFound = false;

for(var i = 0, len = firstArray.length; i < len; i++){
    if(secondArray.indexOf(firstArray[i]) === -1)
    {
         notFound = true;
         break;
    }
}

if(notFound)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Something I just discovered, probably obvious to those with more programming skill is that this will return false if the values in the arrays are different types.  I had to add a parseFloat() conversion in creating the second array to make sure both arrays contained numbers.

Comment: This post has some useful information about the uses of === and what it will fail on.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use

My solution was purely for primitive int types, I can't guarantee it will work for objects, strings etc

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** had read the question too fast, following only works if in same order

```
function same_elements(array1, array2){  
  var result = true; 
  $(array1).each(function(index, value) {
    if (value != array2[index]) {result = false};
  });
  return result;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for array1 = [1,2,3] and array2 = [1,2,1,3]

Comment: yeah, just realized the unordered case