# Push to array and compare two arrays JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare, push

Hello mates once again,

I try to compare two arrays and do something if they have same components or not. I found here  this [Using jQuery to compare two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773069/using-jquery-to-compare-two-arrays) Now i try to use it but obvusly im doing something wrong.

This is my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TDZmQ/) where my code is. I put there two alerts to watch my code but it seems there is something wrong with pushing elements to array?

Here is my code:

### HTML

```
<p class="wyliczanka-element">Heh</p>
<p class="wyliczanka-element">huh</p>
```

### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var wyliczanka_wzor = [Heh, huh];
    var wyliczanka = [];

    $('.wyliczanka-element').each(function (i) {
        wyliczanka.push($(this).text());
    });
    alert(wyliczanka[0]);

    if (($(wyliczanka_wzor).not(wyliczanka).length === 0) && ($(wyliczanka).not(wyliczanka_wzor).length === 0)) {
        alert("Youp!");
    } else {
        alert("meh");
    }
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: jQuery's `.not()` function isn't intended for comparing arrays of strings. What do you expect this: `var wyliczanka_wzor = [Heh, huh];` to do? You don't have variables `Heh` and `huh`, so that line will give you `ReferenceError: Heh is not defined` - should it be `... ["Heh", "huh"]`?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't match this code. Should the Heh and huh in the javascript be in quotes?

Comment: Also your fiddle is having syntax error

Comment: try this `JSON.stringify( wyliczanka_wzor ) == JSON.stringify( wyliczanka )` . or try http://lodash.com/docs#isEqual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing two strings to two undefined variables.

```
var wyliczanka_wzor = [Heh, huh];
```

should be

```
var wyliczanka_wzor = ['Heh', 'huh'];
```