# How to Compare two Arrays are Equal using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want position of the array is to be also same and value also same.

```
var array1 = [4,8,9,10];
var array2 = [4,8,9,10];
```

I tried like this

```
var array3 = array1 === array2   // returns false
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773069/using-jquery-to-compare-two-arrays

Comment: The above is order-indifferent, the OP asks about order-preserved.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

You could use **[Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)**.(*A polyfill is needed for IE < 9 and other old browsers*.)

```
var array1 = [4,8,9,10];
var array2 = [4,8,9,10];

var is_same = (array1.length == array2.length) && array1.every(function(element, index) {
    return element === array2[index]; 
});
```

**[THE WORKING DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/47WCQ/1/)**

Comment: Can i use this one. it also works fine.

Comment: This answer is also found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19746771.  And note it only works for shallow equals (which is totally fine for the example the OP gave).

Comment: Only one little improvement: `(array1.length === array2.length)`. `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: If order isn't important: `(array1.length == array2.length) && array1.every(el => array2.includes(el))`

Comment: @ahmelq sorry but it won't work. [1,2,2,3] compared to [1,2,3,4] returns true

Answer (score 57):

A less robust approach, but it works.

```
a = [2, 4, 5].toString();
b = [2, 4, 5].toString();

console.log(a===b);
```

Comment: what if the array elements are not in the same order? this would not work

Comment: works perfectly if you know that the array is in the same order (like I do). however you could sort the array elements by `sort()` and this should then solve the  op's problem.

Comment: This approach gives the wrong answer if a = `[2, 4, 5].toString()`
and b = `["2,4", 5].toString()`.

Comment: I believe JSON.jstringify would be better for a universal case. However, it is not as performant from what I understand @AndersonGreen

Answer (score 16):

```
var array3 = array1 === array2
```

That will compare whether array1 and array2 are the same array object in memory, which is not what you want.

In order to do what you want, you'll need to check whether the two arrays have the same length, **and** that each member in each index is identical.

Assuming your array is filled with primitives—numbers and or strings—something like this should do

```
function arraysAreIdentical(arr1, arr2){
    if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) return false;
    for (var i = 0, len = arr1.length; i < len; i++){
        if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: Here's a fiddle to play with (same answer, different way to iterate): http://jsfiddle.net/jimschubert/85M4z/

Comment: A multi-dimensional array version is available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript

Answer (score 15):

A more modern version:

```
function arraysEqual(a, b) {
  a = Array.isArray(a) ? a : [];
  b = Array.isArray(b) ? b : [];
  return a.length === b.length && a.every((el, ix) => el === b[ix]);
}
```

Coercing non-array arguments to empty arrays stops `a.every()` from exploding.

If you just want to see if the arrays have the same set of elements then you can use `Array.includes()`:

```
function arraysContainSame(a, b) {
  a = Array.isArray(a) ? a : [];
  b = Array.isArray(b) ? b : [];
  return a.length === b.length && a.every(el => b.includes(el));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives false positives.  For example:  `arraysEqual(23, "")`

Comment: This is deliberate. *not an array* == *not an array*

Comment: I think it's debatable whether or not `arraysEqual` should be allowed to receive non-array inputs at all.  That said, it's still good to be aware of the aforementioned "gotcha".

Comment: My assumption is that it is better to sanitise the inputs than have to wrap every invocation in a `try/catch` block lest it bomb your program. It's a design decision as to what calling it with non-array arguments should do. If you want to throw in this case, then go for it.

Comment: as for me it's better -  const areCollectionsSame = (a: unknown, b: unknown) =>
  Array.isArray(a) && Array.isArray(b) ? a.length === b.length && a.every(el => b.includes(el)) : false;

Comment: Your second function also gives false positives: `arraysContainSame([1,1,2], [1,2,2])`. This is rarely what you want, you probably want to count multiplicity.

Comment: I wrote *if you just want to see if the arrays have the same set of elements* for the second function precisely because ignoring multiplicity was my intention.

Answer (score 7):

You could try this simple approach

```js
var array1 = [4,8,9,10];
var array2 = [4,8,9,10];

console.log(array1.join('|'));
console.log(array2.join('|'));

if (array1.join('|') === array2.join('|')) {
 console.log('The arrays are equal.');
} else {
 console.log('The arrays are NOT equal.');
}

array1 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]];
array2 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]];

console.log(array1.join('|'));
console.log(array2.join('|'));

if (array1.join('|') === array2.join('|')) {
 console.log('The arrays are equal.');
} else {
 console.log('The arrays are NOT equal.');
}
```

If the position of the values are not important you could sort the arrays first.

```
if (array1.sort().join('|') === array2.sort().join('|')) {
    console.log('The arrays are equal.');
} else {
    console.log('The arrays are NOT equal.');
}
```

Comment: The original question stated that the position and value had to be the same.  If the position is not important then you can just sort the two arrays first.

Comment: Converting to string is not reliable, as it fails when the first array is `[4,8,9,10]` and the second is `["4|8",9,10]` for example.

Comment: This was a way easier solution for me I am comparing for exact values between two matrices and don't have bitwise OR operators in my array... @Broxzier

Answer (score 4):

If you comparing 2 arrays but values not in same index, then try this

```
var array1=[1,2,3,4]
var array2=[1,4,3,2]
var is_equal = array1.length==array2.length && array1.every(function(v,i) { return ($.inArray(v,array2) != -1)})
console.log(is_equal)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here goes the code. Which is able to compare arrays by any position.

```
var array1 = [4,8,10,9];

var array2 = [10,8,9,4];

var is_same = array1.length == array2.length && array1.every(function(element, index) {
    //return element === array2[index];
  if(array2.indexOf(element)>-1){
    return element = array2[array2.indexOf(element)];
  }
});
console.log(is_same);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using this! I appreciate how concise this is

Comment: The above code is more usable in many cases. I am using myself.

Comment: This won't work for these two arrays: a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2] and b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3]. Your function will return true. The sort() + toString() method seems the most reliable so far.

Answer (score 2):

Use lodash.
In ES6 syntax:

```
import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual';
let equal = isEqual([1,2], [1,2]);  // true
```

Or previous js versions:

```
var isEqual = require('lodash/isEqual');
var equal = isEqual([1,2], [1,2]);  // true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function isEqual(a) {
if (arrayData.length > 0) {
    for (var i in arrayData) {
        if (JSON.stringify(arrayData[i]) === JSON.stringify(a)) {
            alert("Ya existe un registro con esta informacion");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try doing like this:    `array1.compare(array2)=true`

```
Array.prototype.compare = function (array) {
    // if the other array is a falsy value, return
    if (!array)
        return false;

    // compare lengths - can save a lot of time
    if (this.length != array.length)
        return false;

    for (var i = 0, l=this.length; i < l; i++) {
        // Check if we have nested arrays
        if (this[i] instanceof Array && array[i] instanceof Array) {
            // recurse into the nested arrays
            if (!this[i].compare(array[i]))
                return false;
        }
        else if (this[i] != array[i]) {
            // Warning - two different object instances will never be equal: {x:20} != {x:20}
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: A rule of thumb here is not to mess with objects you don't own. `Array.prototype` is a built-in prototype object for type Arrays and this will cause inconsistency while working in a team.