# Push array if array doesn't exist in array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, loops

I am currently working on a small home project, and I am trying to push an array into an array of arrays, if said array does not already exist in the array of arrays.

```
var arrayArr = [[1,4]];

function pushArr() {

    var tempArr = [1, 3];
    var tempArr2 = [1, 4];

    for(i = 0; i < arrayArr.length, i++)
        if(!arrayArr.indexOf(tempArr[i])) {
            arrayArr.push(tempArr[i]);
        } else {
            //other logic
        }

  }
```

Now, I know this example does not really make sense in the real world, it's just to illustrate my concern. How do I search through an array of arrays to make sure, that I don't create duplicates.

If you have any questions, please ask.

Thanks !

Comment: should `[1,4]` and `[4,1]` be treated as equal in your case?

Comment: No, I don't believe it's necessary, as I have a limited array to push from, that always have the same order.

Comment: In your code you have a small mistake in for condition. Please include `;` after `i < arrayArr.length` instead of `,`

Comment: Nice catch, was just an example though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my solution, in `isArrayInArray()`, I'm looping through each element in the main array `arrayArr`. I'm then comparing if the first and second element of each given array match. If so, the array has been added already so it'll return true.

```js
var arrayArr = [[1, 4]];

pushArray([1, 4]); // does not get added
pushArray([1, 3]); // gets added

console.log(arrayArr);

function isArrayInArray(arrayToSearch, arrayToFind) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayToSearch.length; i++) {
        if (arrayToSearch[i][0] === arrayToFind[0] && arrayToSearch[i][1] === arrayToFind[1]) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

function pushArray(array) {
    if (!isArrayInArray(arrayArr, array)) {
        arrayArr.push(array);
    }
}
```

Comment: This only tests if the first two elements of each array are matched, correct? (i.e., it won't work for arrays of length 3 or more)

Comment: @apsillers Correct! It was done under the assumption that the arrays were only of length 2. I can modify the function is OP requires :)

Comment: Yup, I just wanted to make sure the OP went into this with eyes open; it could indeed be exactly what they need. `:)`

Comment: Exactly what I needed, my array only contains 2 elements each time, so this fits perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You know [1,2] === [1,2] is false.

Please refer to [How to Compare two Arrays are Equal using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395357/how-to-compare-two-arrays-are-equal-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have the following:

```
let a = [1,2];
let b = [1,2];
```

Both `a` and `b` hold two different references to to arrays that have the same numbers. They are not equal !

```js
let a = [1,2];
let b = [1,2];
console.log(a === b);
```

If we by pass this and *we assume that for our problem* that two arrays with the same length and the same data are the same, we can try to call the function `arrayCanBePushed`, before we want to append an array to our array of arrays and if it returns true, then we can proceed with the push.

```js
var arrayOfArrays = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4,5],[7]];

function arrayCanBePushed(arr){
    return !arrayOfArrays.filter(a => a.length === arr.length)
                         .some(a => a.every(ele=>arr.includes(ele)));
}

console.log(arrayCanBePushed([1,2]));
console.log(arrayCanBePushed([1,2,3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to keep the answer as simple as possible. Basically we are iterating over `arrayArr` and checking if all of the elements of the input array match all of the elements of *any* of the element arrays. So it should be simply an `every` nested in a `some`. However if we are comparing just two-element arrays (array to string conversion should be pretty fast) as you have now clarified in your answer then I would use string comparison as illustrated in `pushArr1`. This is the general direction you were heading in your first attempt so I added it to my answer.

```js
var arrayArr = [[1, 3, 5]];
var tempArr = [1, 3, 5];
var tempArr2 = [1, 4];
pushArr1(tempArr);

function pushArr(temp)
{
    if(!arrayArr.some(function(e){
        return e.every(function(e1, i)
        {
          return e1 === temp[i];
        })
      })) arrayArr.push(temp);
      
      console.log(arrayArr);
}


function pushArr1(temp)
{
    if(!arrayArr.some(function(e){return e.join(",") === temp.join(",")})) arrayArr.push(temp);

      console.log(arrayArr);
}
```