# Comparing two arrays inside ng-if

Tags: angularjs

I have array inside a class, and I have to compare if the arrays are same in 2 different objects of the same class. Currently, I am doing it like this,

```
<div class="col-md-4">{{ctrl.Obj1.arr1}}
  <span ng-if="ctrl.Obj2 != null && ctrl.Obj1.arr1 != ctrl.Obj2.arr1"
      class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert" style="margin-left: 6px;
     font-size: small; color: palevioletred">
  </span>
</div>
```

But this is an incorrect way of comparison since it yields different values. My array is of the form: `["string1","string2","string3"]`

What's the correct way to do it?

Edit: My question is different because I am asking about how to accomplish this in AngularJS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Compare two Arrays are Equal using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395357/how-to-compare-two-arrays-are-equal-using-javascript)

Comment: @Rajesh Its not about comparing two arrays, question is more intended on how to do it in angularjs

Comment: @Sajeetharan Is angularJS not a framework on JS? OP is unaware of how to compare arrays and hence he used `arr1 === arr2`. The dupe answers that. Then integrating this logic in angularJS way is his task.

Comment: If you see that way there are thousands of questions should be closed.

Comment: @Sajeetharan lets not debate over it. In my view its dupe, in yours, its not.  Others can vote based on their POV. All in all, we both want to help OP and he/she will get something from both. Have a good day. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing this comparision in template you should have a function that would return boolean value after comparing and then bind that to the template

```
ng-if="compareArrays()"
```

and in controller

```
$scope.compareArrays = function(){
var result = $scope.array1.length == $scope.array2.length && $scope.array1.every(function(element, index) {
    return element === $scope.array2[index]; 
});
 return result ;
}
```

Comment: I guess `array2.includes(element)` should do the trick. That would remove order dependency

Comment: So will every. It is a part of ES6.

Comment: @Sajeetharan , should I not pass the argument to this function? Like `ng-if="compareArrays(ctrl.Obj1.arr1, ctrl.Obj2.arr1)"`. I am asking because that way, I can re-utilize this function everytime I need to do such a comparison of two such arrays?

Comment: you dont need to pass since you already have it inside the controller

Comment: @Sajeetharan, But what if I want to use this function at two different places? I mean to ask, let's say my class has two arrays as attributes (A1 & A2). In the first place, I would like to compare the two values (in two different objects) of A1, and in the second place I would like to compare two values (in two different objects) of A2. Will I have to write another compare function for that then?

Comment: If you have the array in controller, you dont need to duplicate this funciton just call this function and pass the parameters

Comment: Oh! That's what I meant to ask. Pass the parameters from the HTML, like, `ng-if=compareArrays(Obj1.A1.arr1, Obj2.A1.arr2)` and in the second place, `ng-if=compareArrays(Obj1.A2.arr1, Obj2.A2.arr2)` and change the function to `function(arr1,arr2)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160476/discussion-between-sarah-and-sajeetharan).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [angular.equals](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals) to compare two arrays.
Supports value types, regular expressions, arrays and objects.

Here's your use case:

```
<span ng-if="ctrl.Obj2 != null && !angular.equals(ctrl.Obj1.arr1, ctrl.Obj2.arr1)
     class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert" style="margin-left: 6px;
     font-size: small; color: palevioletred">
</span>
```

Don't forget to add the following to your main app controller:
`$scope.angular = angular;`