# How to compare two numbers one is input value and attribute value of the same input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to compare two numbers using jquery?

```
var delivered_qty = [];
var deli_qtydbvalue =[];

var delivered_qty  = 1,2,3
var deli_qtydbvalue =1,4,3

$('.delivered_qty').each(function() {
        delivered_qty.push($(this).val());
       deli_qtydbvalue.push($(this).attr('orginaldbvalue'));
    });
```

here second columns not matching,call ajax here if it is not matching.only call ajax if this is not equals ?

i tried for loop

```
for(var i = delivered_qty.length; i--;) {
        if(delivered_qty[i] !== deli_qtydbvalue[i]){
       $.get("updatedeliverystatus.php", {
            delivered_qty: delivered_qty,
            invoiceitemsID: invoiceitemsID,
            delivered_status: delivered_status,
            getinvoiceno: getinvoiceno
        }).done(function(data) {
        if (data == "1") {
            $.alert({
            title: 'Message',
            type: 'green',
            typeAnimated: true,
            content: 'Delivery Quantity is updated successfully',
            draggable: true,
            })
        }
        });
    }//end if 
    }//end for loop
```

Comment: are those strings?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow, you are asking the wrong question! `deli_qtydbvalue ` and `delivered_qty ` are both a `Array`, try [How to compare Arrays in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: these are numbers

Comment: You've defined them as arrays by using bracket notation.

Answer (score 0):

this query will give you a solution

```js
for(var i = delivered_qty.length; i--;) {
        if(delivered_qty[i] !== deli_qtydbvalue[i]){
        /* calling ajax with async false */
        $.ajax({
    url : "updatedeliverystatus.php",
    type : "get",
    data: {
            delivered_qty: delivered_qty,
            invoiceitemsID: invoiceitemsID,
            delivered_status: delivered_status,
            getinvoiceno: getinvoiceno
        }
    async: false,
    success : function(data) {
      //nothing to do here
    }
 });
 
 /*check if its the last loop. Move it outside the loop for better code readability*/
 if(i == delivered_qty.length -1) {
   $.alert({
            title: 'Message',
            type: 'green',
            typeAnimated: true,
            content: 'Delivery Quantity is updated successfully',
            draggable: true,
            });
 }
      
    }//end if 
    }//end for loop
```

[How to Compare two Arrays are Equal using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395357/how-to-compare-two-arrays-are-equal-using-javascript)