# Is anything wrong comparing with this filter function cause it isn't returning anything at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filter

I'm trying to filter some events on my fullcalendar but I can't get the proper objects that I want to. I'm using the function filter, as the following code:

I have tried using `===` first then i used `==` because I want the values to be the same. I even tried using `&&` to verify if I should use single Strings instead of array

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "connection with API",
            success: function (doc) {
                        listData = doc;
                        console.log("done");
                        $(doc).each(function (idata) {
                            var dt = new Date(doc[idata].EDA);
                            dt.setHours(dt.getHours() + 1);
                            var dt2 = new Date(doc[idata].EDA);
                            dt2.setMinutes(dt2.getMinutes() + 30);
                            var dt3 = new Date(doc[idata].EDA);
                            dt3.setMinutes(dt3.getMinutes() + 30);
                            if (doc[idata].REFERENCE_NUMBER.split("/")[1] == "R9" && doc[idata].CARRIER_CODE_FOR_DISPLAY == "SESE") {
                                allEvents.push({
                                    id: 1,
                                    resourceId: '2',
                                    title: doc[idata].CARRIER_CODE_FOR_DISPLAY + " - " + doc[idata].TRAILER_ID.split("/")[1],
                                    start: doc[idata].EDA,
                                    end: dt,
                                    allday: false,
                                    backgroundColor: '#041E42',
                                    textColor: '#FAFAFA',
                                });
                            }
                            if (doc[idata].REFERENCE_NUMBER.split("/")[1] == "B" && doc[idata].CARRIER_CODE_FOR_DISPLAY == "SESE") {
                                allEvents.push({
                                    id: 2,
                                    resourceIds: ['1','3', '4'],
                                    title: doc[idata].CARRIER_CODE_FOR_DISPLAY + " - " + doc[idata].TRAILER_ID.split("/")[1],
                                    start: doc[idata].EDA,
                                    end: dt3,
                                    allday: false,
                                    backgroundColor: '#041E42',
                                    textColor: '#FAFAFA',
                                });

                            }
                            if (doc[idata].REFERENCE_NUMBER.split("/")[1] == "C" && doc[idata].CARRIER_CODE_FOR_DISPLAY == "SESE") {
                                allEvents.push({
                                    id: 2,
                                    resourceIds: ['3','4'],
                                    title: doc[idata].CARRIER_CODE_FOR_DISPLAY + " - " + doc[idata].TRAILER_ID.split("/")[1],
                                    start: doc[idata].EDA,
                                    end: dt2,
                                    allday: false,
                                    backgroundColor: '#041E42',
                                    textColor: '#FAFAFA',
                                });

                            }

                            if (doc[idata].REFERENCE_NUMBER.split("/")[1] == "R4" && doc[idata].CARRIER_CODE_FOR_DISPLAY== "SESE") {
                                allEvents.push({
                                    id: 2,
                                    resourceId: '1',
                                    title: doc[idata].CARRIER_CODE_FOR_DISPLAY + " - " + doc[idata].TRAILER_ID.split("/")[1],
                                    start: doc[idata].EDA,
                                    end: dt,
                                    allday: false,
                                    backgroundColor: '#041E42',
                                    textColor: '#FAFAFA',
                                });

                                }
                            if (doc[idata].REFERENCE_NUMBER.split("/")[1] == "KD") {
                                allEvents.push({
                                    id: 3,
                                    resourceId: '6',
                                    title: doc[idata].CARRIER_CODE_FOR_DISPLAY,
                                    start: doc[idata].EDA,
                                    end: dt,
                                    allday: false,
                                    backgroundColor: '#94A596',
                                    textColor: '#FAFAFA',
                                    height: ''

                                });
                            }

                        }); 
let eventus3 = allEvents.filter((evento) => {
                    return evento.resourceIds == ['3','4'];
                })
```

Comment: I want the events with resourceIds but the array filter returns me is Always empty

Comment: Either it's a duplicate of [How to Compare two Arrays are Equal using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395357/how-to-compare-two-arrays-are-equal-using-javascript) or [Check if every element in one array is in a second array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628059/check-if-every-element-in-one-array-is-in-a-second-array)

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare arrays this way:

```
evento.resourceIds == ['3', '4'];
```

Objects (arrays included) are compared by reference, that is, == (or ===) returns true only if they point at the same object. Notice that `[1,2]==[1,2]` is false.

One way to simulate a == for arrays would be to compare their JSON representations, so in this example

```
JSON.stringify(evento.resourceIds) === JSON.stringify(['3', '4']);
```

(Not sure if it's the *best*, but probably the most concise).

Answer (score -1):

Arrays are pointers do data, when you do something like `['1', '2'] == ['1', '2']`, you are comparing two differents pointers in the memory, therefore you will obtain `false`, even though the content is the same. If you want to compare two arrays, you should loop through them and see if each element is equal to the element in the other array.

Hope this helps.