# How to compare two lists in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

let's say I have two lists:
1- originalList
2- copiedList

I need to compare my copiedList to originalList. After the first assignment that I'm already doing, I have to check if something happens in the originalList and do the same in the copiedList. I mean if one or more elements get deleted in the originalList I need to do the same with the copiedList(obviously at the same index), or if new elements are added, I need to add them in the copiedList too.

How can I do it in Typescript / Javascript?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Either you can just work with one array and if it changes, you just make a new copy, or you can define a data structure that does it for you.

Comment: https://www.codegrepper.com/search.php?answer_removed=1&q=typescript%20compare%20array or https://stackoverflow.com/a/22395463/495157

Comment: how is one list different from another list then?

Comment: Check this: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer/typescript/example