# How to find the match case using for loop in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have two arrays

```
 var arr1 = [
    {'id':'1','name':'test1','value':'star','role':['monitor']},
    {'id':'2','name':'test2','value':'player','role':['monitor','Supervisor']},
    {'id':'3','name':'test3','value':'saviour','role':['Supervisor']},
    {'id':'4','name':'test4','value':'rock','role':['monitor']},
    {'id':'5','name':'test5','value':'rocky','role':['boxer','monitor']}
]

var arr2 = ['Supervisor','monitor'];
```

I want to get the result where arr2 values is properly matched with arr1 roles values

Persons having both the category should be pushed to arr3.

So result should be `{'id':'2','name':'test2','value':'player','role':['monitor','Supervisor']}`.

if arr2 has one value then we can use `arr1.indexOf(arr2[0])!='-1'` but how to satisfy the "and" condition in the `for` loop..

I don't want to use this if possible, but it's all I can think of:

```
if( arr1.indexOf(arr2[0])!='-1' && arr1.indexOf(arr2[1])!='-1'){
    return arr1[i];
}
```

Comment: you do an array intersection. if the count of the intersection is the same as the count of your `arr2`, then your arr1 entry contains all of the values in arr2.

Comment: Have you considered using a different data structure that could support lookups in a more efficient manner than looping through all records in `arr1`?

Comment: by different data structure you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Marc B and @Terry say, you have just to do an intersection.

Here's a version without Jquery :

```js
function intersection(a, b)
{
  var result = [], ai = 0, bi = 0;
  a.sort();
  b.sort();
  while( a.length > ai && b.length > bi )
  {  
     if(a[ai] < b[bi] ){
       ai++; 
     }
     else if(a[ai] > b[bi] ){ 
       bi++; 
     }
     else
     {
       result.push(a[ai]);
       ai++;
       bi++;
     }
  }
  return result;
}

var arr1 = [
    {'id':'1','name':'test1','value':'star','role':['monitor']},
    {'id':'2','name':'test2','value':'player','role':['monitor','Supervisor']},
    {'id':'3','name':'test3','value':'saviour','role':['Supervisor']},
    {'id':'4','name':'test4','value':'rock','role':['monitor']},
    {'id':'5','name':'test5','value':'rocky','role':['boxer','monitor']}
]

var arr2 = ['Supervisor','monitor'];

var arr3 = [];

arr1.forEach(function(value){
  if(intersection(value.role, arr2).length === arr2.length){
    arr3.push(value);  
  }
});

console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 1):

The main trick here is the equality of the arrays.

```
// Assuming we have array 'equals' method which compares the array equality
// el['role'] == arr2 won't work
var result = arr1.filter(function(el){
  return el['role'].equals(arr2);
});
```

So, we can see that we only have to deal with array equality.
This post [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript) has a lot of discussion about it. Someone has even implemented 'equals' method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jQuery one-liner to compare array—and the best thing is that they don't have to be in the exact same order. [Simply use the `.not()` method, previously mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773069/using-jquery-to-compare-two-arrays-of-javascript-objects).

The only trick is to use [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to loop through your first array, and compare the array of the `role` object against `arr2` using [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```js
var arr1 = [
    {'id':'1','name':'test1','value':'star','role':['monitor']},
    {'id':'2','name':'test2','value':'player','role':['monitor','Supervisor']},
    {'id':'3','name':'test3','value':'saviour','role':['Supervisor']},
    {'id':'4','name':'test4','value':'rock','role':['monitor']},
    {'id':'5','name':'test5','value':'rocky','role':['boxer','monitor']}
]

var arr2 = ['Supervisor','monitor'];

var arr3 = [];
$.each(arr1, function(idx,person){
    if($(person.role).not(arr2).length === 0 && $(arr2).not(person.role).length === 0) {
        arr3.push(person);
    }
});

console.log(arr3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```